# Preview an image and crop it before it's uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a image upload button on my site. This is how I want it to behave:

1. A user clicks a "Choose file" button and selects an image.
2. The image shows before any submission (using javascript FileReader API)
3. A cropping plugin is applied to that image, for instance: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?BEAlLLl9
4. The user chooses the cropping area and hits "Submit".

I need help with the step between 2 and 3. The problem using FileReader API to show images right when they are selected is that hey get a src attribute which is base64 encoded. And the image cropping plugin I've used can't properly find/initialize/draw on the image since it won't recognize the `src=""` attribute as valid.

How can I achieve step 1-4? Surely this has been done before on major sites like Facebook etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://html5.sapnagroup.com/demos/dragDropUploadsCrop/  
This link will guide what you want
http://html5.sapnagroup.com/2012/08/preview-and-crop-before-upload/

```
Files with following extensions are only allowed
        allowedExtensions: ['gif','jpg','jpeg','png','txt'],
        showCropTool: 1,
        sizeLimit: 10737418240, // Maximum filesize limit which works without any problems is 30MB. Current limit is set to 10MB = 10 * 1024 * 1024
        params: {
            'uploadedBy': 'Sapnagroup',
            'x1': '0',  // x coordinates of the image
            'y1': '0',      // x coordinates of the image
            'x2': '300',    // x coordinates of the image
            'y2': '150',    // y coordinates of the image
            'cWidth': '300',        // required crop width
            'cHeight': '150',       // required crop heignt
            'oWidth': '800',        // width of the crop preview image
            'oHeight': '600',       // height of the crop preview image
            'rWidth': '300',        // resize width
            'rHeight': '150'        // resize height
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To show preview of selected file you can use `createObjectURL` method:

   ```
   var windowURL = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;
   var imageUrl = windowURL.createObjectURL(imageFile);
   ```
2. Then when you have image url you can display interface for crop selection.
3. When area to crop where selected you can crop image using canvas.

   ```
   function crop(image, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
     var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

     canvas.setAttribute('width', x2 - x1);
     canvas.setAttribute('height', y2 - y1);

     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     context.drawImage(image, -x1, -y1);

     return canvas;
   }
   ```
4. After that you can get Blob with image from canvas (https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob), which can be uploaded to server using XHR2.